# Android UDP-JPG Stream

Tags: java, android, inputstream, android-bitmap

I send a jpg converted to bytes with C++ to an UDP-Client on Android.

I know that I can convert bytes with the BufferedReader and ImageIO to an JPG, but does this work in Android?

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

BufferedImage bufferImage = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Should I print the jpg to an ImageView or is there a better way?

And is the CPU of an Motorola Moto G fast enough to convert around 15 frames per seconds?

Comment: Even apart from what you are asking, realize that you will need something to handle dropped and re-ordered packets, as UDP allows both, otherwise you will get frames corrupted at least by gaps, especially on wifi in an urban environment.   Perhaps on well performing networks you can get away with just putting in integrity checks and not displaying any damaged frames.

Answer (score 0):

I receive an array of udp data and passit to a a file and then to bitmap like this

```
    public void procesar( ByteArrayOutputStream imagen) {
    Log.d("IMAGEN_PROCESSING", "INSIDE....");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(fullPath, "something" + timeStamp + ".png");
    try {
        File dir = new File(fullPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        file.createNewFile();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        Log.d("File created", file.getAbsolutePath());
        fOut.write(imagen.toByteArray());
        if(fOut!=null){fOut.close();}

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagen.toByteArray(),0,imagen.toByteArray().length);
    notification(context,bmp,file);

}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Creating a file for each frame of a video is a bit absurd

Comment: Rigth. I did not read the question carrefully, I thought he was managing pictures.